# How to generate random numbers with a specified lognormal distribution in R?

Tags: r, random, distribution

I would like to get 20 randomly generated numbers from a lognormal distribution  with the geometric mean of 10 and geometric standard deviation of 2.5.

Which R function should I use to accomplish this task?

Comment: [This explanation](https://msalganik.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/making-sense-of-the-rlnorm-function-in-r/) was helpful for me, including the associated code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `rlnorm` function:

```
rlnorm(20, log(10), log(2.5))
```

More generally distributions in R are generally available in `d`(ensity),`p`(robability),`q`(uantile),`r`(andom) forms with those letters coming first followed by the particular distribution stem: `norm`, `lnorm`, `unif`, `gamma`, ... etc. Their help pages will contain the specifics of the parameters, which can be essential if working with `weibull` or other distribution for which conventions are not completely standardized (as it were).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I generated some numbers using the above code and when I back calculate the geometric mean (GM) and Geometric standard deviation (GSD), GM is slightly off.  I am wondering if this is normal.   Here is the calculation:                         x<-rlnorm(20, log(10),log(2.5))
> describe(log(x))   Mean is 1.99 .  GM = exp(1.99)=7.32     SD= .86 and the GSD = 2.36

Comment: you realize the sample size is 20, right? try a sample size of 1e8 if you want to test convergence.

Comment: If you want to look at the sampling distribution of log-normals with mean 20 and sd 2.5 then try this simple code: `plot(exp( rowMeans( log( matrix(rlnorm(20000, log(20), log(2.5)), ncol=20 )) )) )
`