# Generate lognormally distributed random variable

Tags: r

My random variables X are non-negative. They lie in [0,1] and are log-normally distributed.

I am going to generate log(X) using R's function `rnorm()` due to they are lognormally distributed. Since X is within [0,1], the generated log(X) should be negative for X within [0,1) and be 0 for X=1.

However, `rnorm()` cannot guarantee that the generated log(X) are negative. How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: [Link-1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68394/plot-log-normal-distribution-in-r) and [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058176/how-to-generate-random-numbers-with-a-specified-lognormal-distribution-in-r) . Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rlnorm` instead. More info here: [R_documentation_rlnorm](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Lognormal.html)

Comment: brilliant! I didn't know this function. @Flo.P